# DirectX sample code c++

Tags: directx-11, sample

I'm looking for source code (as I bet a lot of others are / were and will) for learning purposes of DirectX. I would like something similar to the vs2013 Graphics Editor when dealing with *.fbx files, etc. Every thing I find is old and outdated, or way to simple and does not show the basics like transformation cursor, picking objects or points on objects. I'm just looking for something basic.

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) is a good place to start and includes some [tutorial](https://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started) content as well. It supports loading models using the VS 2013 content pipeline that produces CMOs from FBX files.

You didn't state if you were looking to write a Windows desktop application (aka a Win32 application) or if you were looking to write for Windows Store / Windows phone. *DirectX Tool Kit* supports either, although the tutorial is written using a Windows desktop application template so that developers using Windows 7 could also utilize it.

You should also refer to the [DirectX SDK Samples Catalog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/09/20/directx-sdk-samples-catalog.aspx) for locations of updated versions of the legacy DirectX SDK samples that build fine using VS 2013 only.

Comment: Thanks, I will check these out, this will be for a desktop app.